# Improper Integral Involving A Probable Partial Fraction Conversion

Tags: improper-integrals, partial-fractions

I was having trouble evaluating the following integral:$$\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{dx}{(x^2\pm ax+a^2)(x^2\pm bx+b^2)}$$
I have tried approaches that involve converting into partial fractions using thumb rule and without using it.I also tried the online integral calculator. No luck whatsoever. The answer according to the book is:
$$\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{3}}.\frac{a+b}{ab(a^2+ab+b^2)}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have 
$$\frac{1}{(x^2+ax+a^2)(x^2+bx+b^2)} = \frac{cx+d}{x^2+ax+a^2} + \frac{ex+f}{x^2+bx+b^2}.$$
Solving for $c,d,e,f$ one should find
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{(x^2+ax+a^2)(x^2+bx+b^2)} &= \frac{1}{(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)}\left(
\frac{x-b}{x^2+ax+a^2} + \textrm{something similar}\right).
\end{align*}
Now use the hint in the answer by @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner.

**Addendum:**

Letting $x=t-a/2$ we find 
$$\frac{x-b}{x^2+ax+a^2} = \frac{t-(b+a/2)}{t^2+3a^2/4}.$$
The integral 
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dt}{t^2+3a^2/4} \tag{1}
\end{align*}
is a standard integral. 
The integral 
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{t dt}{t^2+3a^2/4} \tag{2}
\end{align*}
is divergent. 
Letting $x=t-b/2$ in the "something similar" above we find terms like (1) and (2) above. 
Call them (3) and (4), respectively. 
Combining (2) and (4) we find we must integrate 
$$\frac{1}{t^2+3a^2/4}-\frac{1}{t^2+3b^2/4}
= (\mathrm{const})\frac{t}{(t^2+3a^2/4)(t^2+3b^2/4)}.$$
This function is integrable on $(-\infty,\infty)$ and odd and therefore integrates to zero.

Comment: A worked out solution will be appreciated. How about just this bit: integration of (x-b)dx/(x^2+ax+a^2)

Comment: @Tanisha: I have added some detail above.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: use that $$x^2+ax+a^2=\left(x+\frac{a}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}a^2$$
and $$x^2+bx+b^2=\left(x+\frac{b}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}b^2$$

Comment: I'd already done that Sir. I'm still confused as to what to do next.

Comment: The question is does the conversion help simplifying into partial fractions? I'm confused because of the a/2 added to x in the first expression and the b/2 in the second.

Comment: set $$t=x+\frac{a}{2}$$